# ReactJs mapping array of items, onClick button always returns the last item of the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this component and I want to be able to call a function with a given item id, but the problem is that when I call `cancelItem` with given parameter, it always returns the id of the last item from the array. I think it has something to do with the scope, but I cannot think of a solution.

### Edit 1: Uploaded a minimal reproducible example

```
import * as React from "react";
import {
  Typography,
  Button,
  Dialog,
  DialogActions,
  DialogContent,
  DialogContentText,
  DialogTitle,
  ListItem,
  ListItemText,
  ListItemButton,
  Box
} from "@mui/material";

interface IItem {
  item_id: number;
  name: string;
}

interface ItemEditModel {
  itemId: number;
}

let items: IItem[] = [
  { item_id: 0, name: "first item" },
  { item_id: 1, name: "second item" },
  { item_id: 3, name: "third item" }
];

export default function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const cancelItem = (item_id: number) => {
    let newItem: ItemEditModel = { itemId: item_id };
    console.log(newItem);
    setOpen(false);
    // do cancel item
  };
  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {items.map((item: IItem, index: number) => (
        <Box key={index}>
          <ListItem>
            <Typography>
              {" "}
              <b>Item {item.name}</b>
            </Typography>
            <ListItemButton onClick={handleClickOpen}>
              <ListItemText primary="Cancel" />
            </ListItemButton>
            <Dialog
              open={open}
              onClose={handleClose}
              aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
              aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
            >
              <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">Cancel</DialogTitle>
              <DialogContent>
                <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
                  Are you sure?
                </DialogContentText>
              </DialogContent>
              <DialogActions>
                <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleClose}>
                  No
                </Button>
                <Button
                  variant="contained"
                  onClick={() => cancelItem(item.item_id)}
                  autoFocus
                >
                  Yes
                </Button>
              </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>
            <ListItemButton onClick={() => console.log(item.item_id)}>
              <ListItemText primary="Edit" />
            </ListItemButton>
          </ListItem>
        </Box>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sampleproblem-973dc4?file=/src/App.tsx:0-2284) is a link to a sandbox.

Comment: I do not see definition of `items` either as a prop or a state variable. Is it coming from outside?

Comment: I did not include them, I am accessing them from redux store. Tried to have my question simple

Comment: Try to add all required code to have a minimal verifiable code.

Comment: Also a simple hack would be to just use index in arg and get data using `items[index]`

Comment: *"when I call cancelEdit"* - Do you mean `cancelItem`?  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] (ideally as a stack snippet in the question, but even off-site in something like Code Sandbox) which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @David will provide.

Comment: [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Comment: @Rajesh updated the code and also inculded a link to a code sandbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the item ID, it's the dialog.  Every click of a button opens *all three* dialogs.  You're just interacting with the last, top-most one.

There are multiple dialogs, but *only one* state indicating whether they are *all* open or closed:

```
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
```

One approach could be to use the item ID as the dialog state.  So start it as `undefined`:

```
const [open, setOpen] = React.useState();
```

And each button can set the state to that item's ID:

```
<ListItemButton onClick={() => handleClickOpen(item.item_id)}>
```

and:

```
const handleClickOpen = (id) => {
  setOpen(id);
};

const handleClose = () => {
  setOpen(undefined);
};
```

Then check if the ID matches to determine if the dialog is open:

```
open={open === item.item_id}
```

Alternatively, with a little more refactoring you can remove the dialog component from the map entirely and have just one dialog overall.  You'd then need to track the state of which record is "currently selected".

Either way, the overall goal is to only display one dialog at a time.

Comment: It works but when it loads the page on the beginning, it renders the dialog box as well, is there any way around it?

Comment: @Sachihiro: I don't see this happening when this change is applied in the Code Sandbox link.

Comment: Yes because at the sandbox, the items are currently present, but suppose that you are waiting for them to arrive from an async api, and at that time, items are undefined which means undefined === undefined => true.

Comment: @Sachihiro: In that case you might add an extra condition in the dialog logic that items exist at all.  Perhaps something like: `open={open === item.item_id && !isLoading}` (depending on how your state manages the asynchronous loading of items).  Or however you've adapted this to your code.  Basically that `open` attribute just needs to know whether or not to open the dialog.